# eslint Failures in Travis CI, but not locally

Tags: node.js, meteor, github, travis-ci, eslint

I have a GitHub [project](https://github.com/enove/thriver) that has passed Travis CI.  Upon creating a [pull request](https://github.com/enove/Thriver/pull/184) for a new feature, Travis CI [fails](https://travis-ci.org/enove/Thriver/jobs/180275453) both pr and push due to two eslint errors:

```
/home/travis/build/enove/Thriver/packages/thriver-accounts/lib/accounts.js
  121:5  error  Strings must use singlequote  quotes
  122:5  error  Strings must use singlequote  quotes
```

Lines 119 through 122 of `accounts.js` are as follows:

```
119: return `Hello ${user.profile.firstname}!\n\n` +
120:  `To verify your account email, simply click the link below.\n\n${url}\n\n` +
121:  `If you weren't expecting this email, simply delete it.\n\n` +
122:  `Thanks!\n\nAll of us at WCASA`;
```

The commit did not even change `accounts.js`, and a local eslint passes without error.  I checked and verified that the versions of node, npm, and meteor are the same locally as they are in Travis CI.

The Travis CI configuration is as follows:

```
{
  "sudo": "required",
  "language": "node_js",
  "node_js": "4.1.1",
  "before_install": [
    "curl -L https://git.io/ejPSng | /bin/sh"
  ],
  "env": "CXX=g++-4.8",
  "addons": {
    "apt": {
      "sources": [
        "ubuntu-toolchain-r-test"
      ],
      "packages": [
        "g++-4.8"
      ]
    }
  },
  "services": "mongodb",
  "script": [
    "meteor npm run lint"
  ],
  "group": "stable",
  "dist": "precise",
  "os": "linux"
}
```

The `.eslintrc` is as follows:

```
{
  "parser": "babel-eslint",
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaVersion": 6,
    "ecmaFeatures": {
      "impliedStrict": true
    }
  },

  "env": {
    "browser": true,
    "node": true,
    "mongo": true,
    "meteor": true
  },

  "extends": [
    "airbnb"
    //"plugin:meteor/recommended"
  ],

  "globals": {
    "Thriver": true,
    "SimpleSchema": true,
    "Marked": true,
    "SHA256": true,
    "google": true,
    "geoXML3": true,
    "AutoForm": true,
    "details_shim": true
  },

  "rules": {
    "no-underscore-dangle": 0,
    "new-cap": 0
  }
}
```

This has happened before in a different file and I "resolved" the issue by having eslint ignore the line.  But I can't do that for every mystery issue.  Any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still have no idea how eslint was passing locally.  Perhaps I was behind in eslint or airbnb version.  However, I realized that the lines really did need to be corrected.  The bottom two lines of code should not use back ticks because there aren't any variables in those strings.

```
119: return `Hello ${user.profile.firstname}!\n\n` +
120:  `To verify your account email, simply click the link below.\n\n${url}\n\n` +
121:  'If you weren\'t expecting this email, simply delete it.\n\n' +
122:  'Thanks!\n\nAll of us at WCASA';
```

Eslint is a lot happier with a concatenated string of different styles than a consistent one where not every segment contains a variable.

Answer (score 0):

http://eslint.org/docs/rules/quotes

This is most likely the fix to your problem.

> JavaScript allows you to define strings in one of three ways: double quotes, single quotes, and backticks (as of ECMAScript 6). For example:

```
/*eslint-env es6*/

var double = "double";
var single = 'single';
var backtick = `backtick`;    // ES6 only
```

> The choice of how to define strings in a codebase is a stylistic one outside of template literals (which allow embedded of expressions to be interpreted). Many codebases require strings to be defined in a consistent manner.

I would try setting one of these rules and running the tests again.

Let me know if this does not fix your problem!

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I added the contents of `.eslintrc` to my post.  I'm using the airbnb style guide, which allows both single and backtick strings.  Furthermore, the eslint passes locally.  It just doesn't pass in Travis CI.